# Call a typescript method when url changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

The following is my typescript angular controller. I want a method to trigger every time when the url changed (even a small part of url e.g. a number).

I made the method what i want to trigger, i have a constructor in the controller. How can i know when to trigger that method and where do i need to  call it? Inside the constructor to initialize it?

This is my controller's code:

```
private returnedClass: Class;
    static $inject: Array<string> = ['$scope', 'common', 'repository.class'];
    constructor(public scope: any, public common: app.core.Common, public myService: app.data.IRepositoryClass) {           
    }           
    getFromDB(): void{
        if (location.href.indexOf("classAdd") !== -1 && typeof this.common.itemId !== 'undefined' && this.common.itemId != null)
        {
          this.myService.getClassById(this.common.itemId).then((returnedItem: Class) => {
              this.returnedClass = returnedItem;
              console.log(this.returnedClass);
            });
        }
    }
}
angular
    .module('app.layout')
    .controller('HeaderNavigationController', HeaderNavigationController);
```

I want to mention that this controller is 1 time executed, when the entire HTML DOM is loaded (index.html). Do i need a watcher or something? How can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using uiRouter listen for the `$stateChangeSuccess` event:

```
constructor(private scope: any, private common: app.core.Common, private myService: app.data.IRepositoryClass) {    

    scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', () => this.getFromDB());
}
```

**Side Note** it is a good practice to mark your dependancies as `private` rather than public.

Comment: i think you missed : "I want a method to trigger every time when the url changed" & "I want to mention that this controller is 1 time executed" part

Comment: yes, i'm using uiRouter but "scope.on is not a function" error